# Performance Lag between Execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing a unique problem related to SQL Server query execution. I have around 150 stored procedures, which load data sequentially to the data warehouse tables.

All stored procedures called inside a while loop one after another. I am observing some lag after one stored procedure completes its execution, and before the next procedure starts its execution. The lag ranges from 3 seconds to 55 seconds between subsequent executions of stored procedures.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you tracking the start and end times of the stored procedure executions?

Comment: Sounds like it's likely a recompile. How complex is that query? Can you capture the execution plan for it? That will tell you how long the recompile took.

Comment: @HandyD, I have an auditing mechnaism, the beginning of the stored procedure execution I log start time and at the end of the execution, I capture end times.

Comment: @GrantFritchey, I also thought about recompile, how I can capture the timings it taking to recompile? The subsequent execution of the stored procedure should not recompile as long as we have that plan in the query cache, right?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is it the stored proc time which is varying or the time in between the proc executions (after the end and before the next start)? Also, is the exec time ever increasing (for each run of this batch)?

Comment: Changes in structures or statistics can lead to recompiles. Check the execution plan. It shows the exact compile time. Or, you can use extended events to capture the recompile event. That will show compile time too, but it's a little harder to capture & access easily.